# Internet Explorer creating files when I am not using it

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, ccleaner

I never use Internet Explorer (your welcome) or Microsoft Edge. However, when I run CCLeaner after using Google Chrome, there is always many megabytes worth of random files like history. What can I do to stop this, and why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know how to stop it, so this is a comment rather than an answer. The reason why it is happening, is because Internet Explorer is often used as a COM object in other programs and scripts. For example, whenever you use a vbscript to perform an action such as retreiving information from a webpage, it creates a COM object of Internet Explorer. The same applies for Outlook when you select to view the content of a HTML email. Now, whenever a program displays html content using this COM object, temporary internet files are created and files are made. This includes online and local files.

Comment: LPChip is correct, but there's even more to it.  Even when IE is not used as a COM object in other programs and scripts, it still has pieces that run.

Answer (score -1):

Building on what LPChip said, since internet explorer is going to be used if it is still available by other programs and scripts, a good way to stop this to simply uninstall it.

Here's how to do it:

- Click the Start button Picture of the Start button, type Programs and Features in the search box, then click View installed updates in the left pane.
  Under Uninstall an update, scroll down to the Microsoft Windows section.
- Right-click Windows Internet Explorer 9, click Uninstall, then click Yes when prompted.
- Click one of the following:
  Restart now (to finish the process of uninstalling Internet Explorer 9 and restore the previous version of Internet Explorer).
  Restart later

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/how-do-i-install-or-uninstall-internet-explorer-9